# Is it possible to animate Angular 2's ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, ng-switch

Is it possible to animate this at all? I have this block of code

```
div([ngSwitch]="switchState")
  ul(fxLayout="row", fxLayoutAlign="space-between", *ngSwitchCase="0")
   some-list
  ul(fxLayout="row", fxLayoutAlign="space-between", *ngSwitchCase="1")
   second-list  
  ul(fxLayout="row", fxLayoutAlign="space-between", *ngSwitchCase="2")
   third-list
```

actual switch functionality is working fine, I want to animate it but Im not exactly sure what css property angular plays with, I suspect at the time it doesnt even exist in the DOM, so is it possible to animate new additions to the DOM?

Comment: transition-duration would be a good css property to try out.

Comment: What markup is this?

Comment: It looks like pug/jade to me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to animate ng-switch using [Angular2 animation system](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html).

You can read more about it in the docs, but the gist is that you can animate any element that is being added to DOM. When using `*ngSwitchCase` elements are removed and inserted into the DOM based on condition. This state is called the `void` state & you can choose what animation to apply as it transitions from `void` state to being visible.

Given the following markup that uses `ngSwitch`:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="val">
   <p *ngSwitchCase="true" [@enterTrigger]="'fadeIn'">Value is TRUE</p>
   <p *ngSwitchCase="false" [@enterTrigger]="'fadeIn'">Value is FALSE</p>
</div>
```

You can define animations in the component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  animations: [
    trigger('enterTrigger', [
    state('fadeIn', style({
        opacity: '1',
        transform: 'translateY(50%)'
    })),
    transition('void => *', [style({opacity: '0'}), animate('500ms')])
    ])
  ]
})
```

Here the `void => *` transition determines how the element will be animated as it moves from `void` state to any state (including becoming visible)

Plunkr demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/IPLImRt34esClBg1HZdm?p=preview

**P.S.** Don't forget to install `@angular/animations`

Comment: Thank you very much!! This worked!! I can't upvote, not enough rep :)

Comment: angular > 4  - don't forget to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` in `app.module.ts`

Comment: plunkr does not work